# Parse HTML From URL

Tags: windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I need to download an HTML file and parse it to extract certain tags. Short of building my own parser, is there a way to do this in C++/CX?

I tried using `XmlDocument`, but obviously ran into problems thanks to XML having much stricter rules than HTML.

I also tried several libraries which I found online, all of which failed due to differences between C++/CLI and C++/CX.

I would need one of the following:

- A built-in class or set of methods to parse HTML
- A library which works in C++/CX
- Another method of extracting tags and attributes

I realize that roll-your-own would be the fallback, but building an HTML parser can be a daunting task, to say the least.

Any and all ideas would be appreciated.